# ionic 2 build error on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, angular, ionic2

I imported my ionic 2 app into the visual studio. Before I did that, There was not any build error but, know it gives me following errors;

[image]

this is my firms.ts file;

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FirmService } from '../../providers/getFirms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {ReportsPage} from '../report/report';
import { Auth } from '../../providers/auth';
import {LoginPage} from '../login-page/login-page';
import { NavController, ModalController, AlertController, LoadingController,NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormControl

} from '@angular/forms';

/*
  Generated class for the Firms page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-firms',
  templateUrl: 'firms.html'
})
export class FirmsPage {
  langs;
  langForm;
  loading: any;
  username : string;
  firms: string[];


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, public firmService: FirmService, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public authService: Auth) {
     this.getFirms();
     this.username = this.navParams.get("param");
     this.langForm = new FormGroup({
      "langs": new FormControl('')
    });
  }
```

how can it cannot find them. I think, I imported correct paths.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not taking the correct names of those Providers. Remember that you have to make reference to the class name.

```
export class AuthService { }
```

Comment: nope, I am using correct class name. the app is already running before I imported it to visual studio. The problem is something releated with typings and typescript

Answer (score 0):

Both seem related to the providers route, are you 100% sure its correct? It would be easier to answer your question if you could make a jsfiddle or link to a repo.

Answer (score 0):

1 - install **npm** https://nodejs.org

2 - install **typescript** `npm install -g typescript`

3 - Change the settings in VS to use your PATH first, this is the main issue always when you install npm, VS now comes with npm embedded.

```
Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> External Web Tools
```

Select **$(PATH)** and with the arrows (right corner) move the PATH to the first row.